# How can we get an absolute value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can we get an absolute value in mongodb for example in SQL query..

```
SELECT ABS(-20)
Result
20
```

Which command we have to use to get absolute value in mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like  { $abs: number }

See documentation :  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/